# How to change absolute path to relative path in Typescript after build

Tags: typescript, webpack

I create Typescript react UI kit (like bootstrap) for team. We decide that we publish private package.

the problem is that the `.d.ts` files after build have absolute path, so type information is not found after build

```
//tsconfigs.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        // ...
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationMap": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./lib",
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "strict": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "@/*": ["packages/*"]
        },
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
    },
    "include": ["./packages", "./stories"]
}
```

```js
//webpack.config.js
//...

module.exports = (env) => {
    return {
        devtool: 'inline-source-map',
        entry: './packages/index.tsx',
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.svg', '.scss', '.ttf'],
            alias: {
                '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'packages')
            }
        },
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'lib'),
            filename: 'index.js',
            library: '@example/example',
            libraryTarget: 'umd'
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.tsx?$/,
                    loader: 'ts-loader',
                    exclude: /lib/,
                    options: {
                        onlyCompileBundledFiles: true
                    }
                }
                // ...
            ]
        },
        externals: {
            react: 'react',
            reactDOM: 'react-dom'
        }
        // ...
    };
};
```

How can I use relative paths after webpack build?